To select the first closed round of an image while reading it from left to right

Here, I used the character image like this. When I tried to select only the first closed round portion of the input image, while scanning it from left to right using open_cv -, I got the whole outer edge portion of the character. How do I get only ROI?
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def find_closed_round_areas(image_path):
    # Load the image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    # Apply binary thresholding
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    # Find contours
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Create a color version of the original image
    color_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    # Filter and highlight closed round contours
    highlighted_image = color_image.copy()
    for contour in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 100:  # Filter out small contours
            perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
            circularity = 4 * np.pi * cv2.contourArea(contour) / (perimeter ** 2)
            if circularity > 0.7:  # Filter based on circularity
                cv2.drawContours(highlighted_image, [contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)  # Green color in BGR

    # Display the original and highlighted images
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.title('Original Image')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(color_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.title('Highlighted Closed Round Areas')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(highlighted_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.show()

# Path to the image
image_path = '/mnt/data/ROI_65.png'

# Find and highlight the closed round areas
find_closed_round_areas(image_path)

This is the code. But it selects the outer box of the picture, not the ROI.

Because the outer edge is the first closed loop returned by the algorithm because it's the loop containing all others.
change the RetrievalModes from external
 contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

to
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

you can then filter out loops that are too large
image_area = image.shape[0] * image.shape1
# Filter out contours that are larger than 95% of the image area
filtered_contours = [contour for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) <= 0.95 * image_area]

From the docs:

RetrievalModes
RETR_EXTERNAL  Python: cv.RETR_EXTERNAL
retrieves only the extreme outer contours. It sets
hierarchy[i][2]=hierarchy[i][3]=-1 for all the contours.
RETR_LIST  Python: cv.RETR_LIST
retrieves all of the contours without establishing any hierarchical
relationships

Full example
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    image_path = 'ROI_65.png'
    def find_and_plot_inner_contours(image_path):
        # Load the image
        image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    
        # Apply binary thresholding
        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    
        # Find contours
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        # Assuming you have already read the image and found contours
    
        image_area = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1]
    
        # Filter out contours that are larger than 95% of the image area
        # and too small contorurs
        filtered_contours = [contour for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour)>100 and cv2.contourArea(contour) <= 0.95 * image_area]
    
        print("amount of countours detected",len(filtered_contours))
    
        # Create a color version of the original image
        color_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    
    
        highlighted_image = color_image.copy()
        i=1
        for contour in filtered_contours:
            perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
            circularity = 4 * np.pi * cv2.contourArea(contour) / (perimeter ** 2)
            print("cricularity",circularity)
            if circularity > 0.3:  # Filter based on circularity
    
    
                cv2.drawContours(highlighted_image, [contour], -1, (0, 150, 0), thickness=2)  
    
                break 
    
    
        # Display the original and also the countours
        plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
        plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
        plt.title('Original Image')
        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(color_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
        plt.title('inner Contours')
        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(highlighted_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
       

find_and_plot_inner_contours(image_path)

getting this error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

@Ayyoobareacode I added a full example
